# java unable to connect to JDBC URL that uses PKI (public key encryption)

Tags: java, security, jdbc, certificate

I am trying to connect to a jdbc url that uses TCPS.
I have already setup wallets and imported the certificates in keystore (key pair generated and public keys are exchanged)

While trying to connect to the JDBC from java client, I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
```

Here is my code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();

ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:/@pkidb_ssl");
            
            
// ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:/@SAMPLEDB_RO");
Provider p;
p = new OraclePKIProvider();
Security.insertProviderAt(p, 3);
conn = ds.getConnection();

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM V$VERSION");    
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
String val = rs.getString(1);
System.out.println("Output: " + val);
rs.close();
ps.close();

System.out.println("Finished");
```

I am able to connect to the keystore from command prompt and view the contents. I have already passed the JVM parameters like below:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="<path-to-jdk>/lib/security/cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="changeit"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="<path-to-jdk>/lib/security/cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

It appears that either JDBC is referring to a different or internal JVM or there is another way to specify the password.

Please note, I am able to view the certificates from command line and the password is correct.

How do I know which key store or trust store is used here and what is the password it is trying to use internally?

UPDATE:
After debugging I found a strange behaviour.
I have set following additional JVM arguments
-Doracle.net.wallet_password , -Doracle.net.wallet_location

when i debug I found that the connection tries to use **oracle.net.wallet_location** instead of the keystore and keystore password properties.

i.e. The keystore that java reads is from wallet_location and not from keyStore or trustStore location (Same holds true for the password).

Comment: So the keystore password was incorrect. `cacerts` is a truststore, not a keystore.

Comment: No the password is correct as i can use the same password from command prompt and it works

Comment: I tried adding another keystore (keystore.jks) file and the issue is same. Same password works while using keytool but in java (jdbc) i see this error.